An manually added external library is not appended to the classpath system property. Why?
I'm collaborating on an app whose printing capabilities rely on the OpenOffice library. Furthermore, it reads the system property java.class.path in runtime
I downloaded the OpenOffice installer from the library's official website, installed it, and then manually added the unoil.jar file (program/classes) as my module's dependency. The dependency's scope is compile, though I tried runtime and provided as well. I use IntelliJ's default build, I don't build the project with Maven before hitting the Run button
It may be noteworthy that the library is highlighted in orange in the External Libraries section, like the Target directory. It usually means it's excluded
When the app runs and queries the java.class.path system property, the library's path is not listed in it (which I observed with the debugger). The module's Maven dependencies from .m2, on the other hand, are listed. Since it can't find the jar, the execution results in an error
What may be the problem?

...and then manually added... Why? You need to add it as a pom dependency
